# Where am i going wrong, trying to recursively scrape?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I want to scrape a site with scrapy that lists its products in catagories  i'm new to scrapy and just getting my head round it today but though i was getting the gist of it on simple scrapes so attempted to scrape urls and return them to scrape further but appears i'm missing something.

someone answered fixing my code here is the latest version as thought i'd have another go at learning scrapy today but its still not recursively scanning it just seems to loop through all the pages but never gets into parse the items

never seems to enter the else statement

yield scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse_item)

i can debug it to check the items are parsed correctly if i force it to output items without looping

if i change the following

```
if product_pages:
            for product_url in product_pages:
                product_url2 = str(self.base_url + product_url)
                self.log("Queued up: %s" % product_url2)
                yield scrapy.Request(url = product_url2,callback = self.parse_product_pages)
        else: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse_item)
```

to

```
if product_pages:
            for product_url in product_pages:
                product_url2 = str(self.base_url + product_url)
                self.log("Queued up: %s" % product_url2)
                yield scrapy.Request(url = product_url2,callback = self.parse_item)
        else: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse_product_pages)
```

here is my code i'm working in python 2.7

```
    import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from ybscrape.items import Product
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class ybracingSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ybscrape2'
    download_delay = 0.75


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ybracingSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.allowed_domains = ['http://www.ybracing.com/', 'www.ybracing.com', 'www.esellepro.com']
        self.base_url = 'http://www.ybracing.com'
        self.start_urls = ['http://www.ybracing.com/karting/']

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        category = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()


        #loop over catagory pages take the product link and add all pages url
        for product in category:
            all_pages = '?itemsperpage=99999'
            category_url = str(self.base_url + product + all_pages)
            self.log("Queued up: %s" % category_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = category_url,callback = self.parse_product_pages)

    def parse_product_pages(self, response):
        product_pages = response.xpath("//li/div/div/h3/a/@href").extract()


    #print("debug pause")
    #print(product_pages)
    #wait = input("PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE.")
    #print("continue")

        if product_pages:
            for product_url in product_pages:
                product_url2 = str(self.base_url + product_url)
                self.log("Queued up: %s" % product_url2)
                yield scrapy.Request(url = product_url2,callback = self.parse_product_pages)
        else: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse_item)  

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = Product()


    item['description'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='Tabbed-Container-Details']/div[2]/div/text()").extract()
    item['product_title'] = response.xpath("//h3[@class='Product-Heading']/text()").extract()
        item['price'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='Product-Price']/text()").extract()
    table_rows = response.xpath("//table[@id='SpecificationTab']/tr[*]/td[1]//text()").extract()



        yield item
```

my items.py

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Product(Item):
  product_title = Field()
  description = Field()
  price = Field()
```

What i'm expecting my code to do in steps

1. grab all the links within the the first export (categories) (this works)
2. look at all 9999 products inside each category and export the list (this works)
3. take the product url from the export append it to the base url to get to the product page for each. (this works)
   4.then read data from in the product page to add to items ( never gets here) unlese i skip the if statement but thats not recursive it wont handle sub catagories like that

Comment: You'll need to give more information on what you get vs. what you expect. What works, what does not work, share your crawl stats etc.

Comment: Could you clarify where is this recursion happening?

Comment: Use scrapy's urljoin `product_url = response.urljoin(product_pages[0])` Also, I'm afraid it gives an error on this line `product_url = str(self.base_url + product_page)` there is no variable called `product_page`

Comment: sorry that was a typo was supposed to be product_pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I have made some changes in your code and now it's working

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from demo.items import DemoItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class DemoSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'ybracing2'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DemoSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.allowed_domains = ['http://www.ybracing.com/', 'www.ybracing.com', 'www.esellepro.com']
        self.base_url = 'http://www.ybracing.com'
        self.start_urls = ['http://www.ybracing.com/racewear/']

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        category = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()


        #loop over catagory pages take the product link and add all pages url
        for product in category:
            all_pages = '?itemsperpage=99999'
            category_url = str(self.base_url + product + all_pages)
            self.log("Queued up: %s" % category_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url = category_url,callback = self.parse_product_pages)

    def parse_product_pages(self, response):
        product_pages = response.xpath("//div[@class='Product']/a/@href").extract()

        if product_pages:
            for product_url in product_pages:
                product_url2 = str(self.base_url + product_url)
                self.log("Queued up: %s" % product_url2)
                yield scrapy.Request(url = product_url2,callback = self.parse_item)
        else: 
            yield scrapy.Request(url = response.url,callback = self.parse_product_pages)  

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = DemoItem()
        dirty_data ={}
        item['product_title'] = response.xpath("//h3[@class='Product-Heading']/text()").extract()
        item['price'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='Product-Price']/text()").extract()
        item['description'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='Tabbed-Container-Details']/div[2]/div/text()").extract()
        #image['product_image'] = 

        # for variable in dirty_data.keys():
            # if dirty_data[variable]: 
                # if variable == 'price':
                    # item[variable] = float(''.join(dirty_data[variable]).strip().replace('$', '').replace(',', ''))
                # else: 
                    # item[variable] = ''.join(dirty_data[variable]).strip()
        yield item
```

Comment: i noticed last night i missed the second for loop :) but still confused why its not working, can you explain why you added @class to the xpaths i thought the xpath alone was enough to id the section.

Comment: and it loops through correctly can you explain the addition of class to xpath

Comment: I have used exact element's location but can you explain what you want to know?